# How to force ms access form controls to generate code rather than macros

Tags: vba, ms-access

Access 2021 generates macros for form controls instead of vba code.  How can I force ms access to generate code instead?

Answer (score 2):

If you using the wizard for an "action" such as close form, you can't - they use macros.

However, are you adding a control with designer?

If you drop the control on the page - not use wizard, then you can right click say on a button, and choose this:

Then you get this prompt:

[image]

Then you get this:

[image]

So, you can choose macro, or VBA (code builder).

And if you get somewhat tired, you can CHANGE the default in Access to always use + assume you want to use VBA.

file->options->Object designers

And choose this option:

[image]

Now, when you right click on a control/button, and choose build Event, it will jump directly to VBA edit - and NOT assume you want to use a macro.

HOWEVER, this does NOT change the behavior of using button and control wizards.

That would be this setting:

drop the ribbon for controls, and un-check this:

[image]

However, quite a few moons ago (access 2010???), they changed this to ALWAYS use macros for the button wizards, and you can NOT change this.

However, the kinds of operations are REALLY basic, and you should not care. Say to close a form, and do a few "simpleton" kinds of things.

Say, I have wizards "on", and I click on a button in the ribbon, and then click in the form.

You get this:

[image]

If I don't want a "wizard" at this point, just hit cancel. Right click, build event.  (and with that default changed to use VBA - you jump right to code editor).

However, just keep in mind that if you use the wizard from above such as close form, you get a macro.

You CAN change macros to VBA. And while somewhat of a face plant, the convert to VBA option is grayed out when you open the macro like this:

[image]

So, close macro editor, and choose this option:

[image]

So, what I do?

Well, for a wizard button to close a form? Who cares - it just a close form - don't care if it is VBA or macro.

But, for all my button code that I write? Then I just hit cancel on the wizard prompt, or as per above, un-check in ribbon the user wizards.

But, many moons ago, you could have the button wizards generate VBA or macro. They to my knowledge for a very long time now - at least since 2010, maybe 2007, they generate macro code.

You can as noted, convert the code to VBA, or simply not use the button wizards.

Last but not least?
Well, if the convert to code is grayed out, what is it for???

It is ONLY un-gray (enabled) WHEN you open a NON form/report macro.

So, for example, I choose this - a stand alone macro - NOT in a form

eg: right click on a macro like this:

[image]

Now I get this:
[image]

So, this is a stand alone macro - and you can thus use in the macro editor, the option to convert the above macro code to VBA if you wish.