# Microsoft Access - don't find newly created form in VBA Project Explorer

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I am new to MS-Access / VBA (inherited an old project). I just created a form with buttons and text boxes etc. I was expecting it to appear in the VBA project explorer window, but it doesn't.  I need to add code for click events and form_load etc using VBA.  In the Access UI, I can select a click event, but that leads to some sort of weird macro builder GUI and not the standard VBA editor.
[image: Image here]

I also tried looking for hidden forms and also tried restarting Access.

Comment: In `OnClick` select `[Event Procedure]`, then the `[...]`. The Form must be in Design View (not Layout View).

Comment: see here for a setting to always create VBA event procedures: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73355004/how-to-force-ms-access-form-controls-to-generate-code-rather-than-macros

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force ms access form controls to generate code rather than macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73355004/how-to-force-ms-access-form-controls-to-generate-code-rather-than-macros)

Comment: One more note: the forms only appear in the VBA project explorer if they have VBA code behind or if they have the `HasModule` property set.

Answer (score -1):

Olivier Jacot-Descombes answer that the form must be in Design View (not Layout view) worked for me and resolved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).